# Python classifier predicts a numpy array with 2+ elements while it should only have 1 element

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm training a cascade of classifiers for text classification and I'm struggling quite a bit with some of the scikit-learn tools. I define X = data, y = sub_label, z = super_label

```
#Cross validation sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, z_train, z_test = train_test_split(X, y, z, test_size=0.25, random_state=None)

unique_super_labels = set(z_train)

#Training a dictionary of classifiers
clf2 = {}

#Building the pipeline (vectorizer => transformer => classifier)
pipeline = Pipeline([('vect', HashingVectorizer(analyzer=my_analyzer,
                                                stop_words=['super', ':', 'auchan', 'produit', 'ls', 'et',
                                                            'inconnu', 'de', 'ou'])),
                     ('clf', LogisticRegression()
)])

#Classifier for super_labels:
clf2["super_label_classifier"] = pipeline.fit(X_train, z_train)

# Classifiers for sub_labels:
 for super_label in unique_super_labels:  
     pipeline = Pipeline([('vect', HashingVectorizer(analyzer=my_analyzer,
                                                     stop_words=['super', ':', 'auchan', 'produit', 'ls',
                                                                 'et', 'inconnu', 'de', 'ou'])),
                          ('clf', LogisticRegression()
     )])
     data, target = [], []
     for i in range(len(z_train)):
         if z_train[i] == super_label:
             data.append(X_train[i])
             target.append(y_train[i])
     if not all(x == target[0] for x in target):  # this is to avoid super_label with only one sub_label
         clf2[super_label] = pipeline.fit(data, target)
     else:
         clf2[super_label] = clf2["total"]

#Predict
z_predicted = clf2["total"].predict(X_test)
y_predicted = []
for x in X_test:
    super_label_predicted =  clf2["super_label_classifier"].predict(x)
    label_predicted = clf2[super_label_predicted].predict(x)
    y_predicted.append(x)
```

I get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jmm/PycharmProjects/text_classification/tc.py", line 62, in <module>
    label = clf2[super_label_predicted].predict(x)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

It is because *super_label_predicted* should be a numpy array with only one element but it seems to have multiple elements and I don't understand why. My *z_predicted* array seems well defined. It has a fair accuracy score of 0.64 for 2500 samples when compared to *z_test*.

Do you have any idea what's going on?

Comment: `For super_label in unique_super_labels`, so it would be actually good to know what `unique_super_labels` is and where you defined it.

Comment: Thanks. It's earlier in the code: unique_super_labels = set(z_train)

Comment: scikit-learn classifiers always return NumPy arrays from `predict`. Please post the actual traceback, so we know where the error originates.

Comment: Done. It's in Debug mode (with Pycharm).

Comment: Could you maybe resolve the origin of `unique_super_labels`. You already wrote it comes from `z_train` but where does this one come from, etc. I mean if you do `type(super_label)` it will tell you that it is a `numpy.ndarray` so at some point you've set it to one.

Comment: Sorry I just read the traceback, I thought the error already occured in your first `for` loop but it occurs only in the very last. So obviously the return value of `predict` is a `numpy.ndarray` (as already indicated by larsmans). You should check the documentation for that.

Comment: OK I added extra information that maybe were important. I know it should give me a numpy array but it should only have one element in it which is not the case.

Comment: Even if it had only one element your code would throw an exception. You would have to do `clf2[super_label_predicted[0]]` instead. And in case of multiple return values you should really consider the documentation of `predict` to find out what you actually get back. Maybe you can just stick with `super_label_predicted[0]`.

Comment: OK but when I check what is inside super_label_predicted, I find different values... so I don't know which one select... That's really weird.